# How to get values from the loop in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, monte-carlo

Could you tell me please how to obtain separate values of "pi" depending on the value of N (code below)? 
For example If I write "pi1" I will get a value of "pi" for N(1) where N(1)=100. If I write "pi2" I will get "pi" for N(2)=1000 etc. I need it to compare the calculation time and the accuracy.

**My CODE is:**

```
R=1; 
N=[100,1000,10000,100000]; 

for k=1:1:4 
  toc
   x = 2*rand(N(k), 1)-1; 
   y = 2*rand(N(k), 1)-1; 
   in_circle = find((x.^2+y.^2)<R.^2); 
   N2 = size(in_circle, 1); 

   pi=4*N2/(N(k)*R.^2) 
  t=toc
end
```

**Actual OUTPUT is:**

```
pi = 
3.120000000000000 
t = 
1.088773407512715e-004 

pi = 
3.208000000000000 
t = 
5.176135871781760e-005 

pi = 
3.145600000000000 
t = 
6.113194952018113e-005 

pi = 
3.143360000000000 
t = 
1.124470896283624e-004
```

**OUTPUT I would like to get:**

```
pi1 = 
3.120000000000000 
t1 = 
1.088773407512715e-004 

pi2 = 
3.208000000000000 
t2 = 
5.176135871781760e-005 

pi3 = 
3.145600000000000 
t3 = 
6.113194952018113e-005 

pi4 = 
3.143360000000000 
t4 = 
1.124470896283624e-004
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want the variables to be called `pi1, pi2, ...`, you can build the variable names using `eval`:

```
for k=1:1:4
  ...
  eval(['pi' num2str(k) ' = 4*N2/(N(k)*R.^2)'])
  ...
end
```

But a more typical thing to do would be to use an array:

```
for k=1:1:4
  ...
  pi(k) = 4*N2/(N(k)*R.^2)
  ...
end
```

If you're not planning on using the names of the `pi` variables later in your code, you might just use `disp` to write the statement that you actually want:

```
for k=1:1:4
  ...
  pi = 4*N2/(N(k)*R.^2)
  disp([num2str(k) ': ' num2str(4*N2/(N(k)*R.^2))])
  ...
end
```

Etc.

Comment: [Alternatives to the `eval` Function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html) from The MathWorks. Better than straight `eval` is [`genvarname`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/genvarname.html), which is subject for future replacement by options only available in R2014a+.

Comment: That's not an alternative to `eval`. You might need `getvarname` to construct the variable name in a way that's legal, but you still have to do the `eval`. The example is right there in the page you linked to.